# How to add file path to the command line argument in python

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to do image comparison in python. I need to establish two command line arguments, --first  and --second , which are the paths to the two respective input images.How can I add image file path to these command line arguments.

I have tried placing the image file paths manually in place of first and second command line arguments by the commands written below but it didnt work .

```
   ap.add_argument("-f", "--C:\Users\admin\original-01", required=True,
        help="first input image")
   ap.add_argument("-s", "--C:\Users\admin\modified-01", required=True,
        help="second")
```

#This is the actual code
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

```
      # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
            ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
            ap.add_argument("-f", "--first", required=True,
        help="first input image")
            ap.add_argument("-s", "--second", required=True,
        help="second")
            args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

This error appears

```
  usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -f FIRST -s SECOND
  ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -s/- 
  -second
```

Comment: Your code is completely messed up. It is not clear what your actual code looks like.

Comment: When you pass the filepath on the command line, does any filepath have any spaces in it? If so, you'll see to surround the filepath with quotes in order to avoid the args splitting on that space in the filepath.

Comment: the `ap.parse_args()` function takes an optional argument...

Comment: Hey sorry if it's messed up. I have explicitly mentioned the actual code where first and second are command line arguments which are supposed to be file paths. I just need to know how to place the file path in place of first and second? In the two commands at the beginning I have tried to pass the file paths , it has no space and its in inverted commas. Just like to know if it's the right way to add file path in command line argument. If it's right then why the error mentioned at the last didnt go ?

Comment: You run your script like `python script.py -f /path/to/first.jpg -s /path/to/second.jpg` in the command line, not in your python code. The `argparse` module helps you parse the arguments, it doesn't insert the arguments.

Comment: Alright. I am using Jupyter notebook installed through Anaoconda3 in windows 8. Kindly guide how do I run the script in the command line? Jupyter provides Python IDE.

Comment: Is this a `Notebook` or a Python script?  You can't provide commandline values to a Notebook.